# How to change property values for an object nested in an array in graphql?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I've just started to learn GraphQL recently and have decided to implement it in a react based polling app where users can create and vote on polls.
I've created a mongoose model that looks like this https://github.com/luckyrose89/Voting-App/blob/master/backend/models/poll.js. 
I'm facing an issue with adding upvotes to a poll option while writing Graphql mutations. So far my schema looks like this:

```
const AnswerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Answer",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    option: { type: GraphQLString },
    votes: { type: GraphQLInt }
  })
});

const QuestionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Question",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    question: { type: GraphQLString },
    answer: { type: GraphQLList(AnswerType) }
  })
});

const AnswerTypeInput = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: "AnswerInput",
  fields: () => ({
    option: { type: GraphQLString },
    votes: { type: GraphQLInt }
  })
});

const QuestionTypeInput = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: "QuestionInput",
  fields: () => ({
    question: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    answer: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(AnswerTypeInput)) }
  })
});

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    addPoll: {
      \\\\ code here
    },

    deletePoll: {
    \\\\\ code here
    },

    upvotePoll: {
      type: QuestionType,
      args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
      resolve(parent, args) {}
    }
  }
});
```

So I've defined my types and I can add and delete polls and access a single poll(I've skipped my queries section here). But I don't understand how to access a single poll's AnswerType object without retrieving unnecessary data and use it to write my upVote mutation.
I hope someone can guide me with this